# XmlSlurper get node value clarification

Tags: java, xml, grails, groovy, xml-parsing

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I want to read the value of the particular tag, I'm using XMLSlurper, below is my code

```
String sample ='to'
def person = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File("C:\\Desktop\\note.xml"))
println  person.to
```

for the above getting the answer = `Tove`.

But when I pass the tag name as string I'm not getting the value

```
String sample ='to'
def person = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File("C:\\Desktop\\note.xml"))
println  person.sample
```

getting empty string

Let me know how can I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example you should use use your variable like this and let it be interpreted as a GString:

```
String sample ='to'
def person = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File("I:/Work/test.xml"))
println  person."${sample}"
```